# How to return bool value with Popup Page from Rg.Plugins.Popup

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I learning xamarin and trying to use the puglin [Rg.Plugins.Popup](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup)  this plugin is usefull to create Popup page

I would like to return boolean value when user click on yes (true) or no (false) on the PopPup Page.

Here is my Xaml code :

```
<Label x:Name="NoLabel"ClassId="1">
<Label.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnNopeorYesPopUp"  />
</Label.GestureRecognizers>
</Label>
<Label x:Name="YesLabel">
<Label.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnNopeorYesPopUp"  />
</Label.GestureRecognizers>
</Label>
```

Here is how I would like use the function (OnNopeorYesPopUp) that returns the boleans in my YesOrNotPopup class but it is not possible :

```
 public bool OnNopeorYesPopUp(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var LabelTapped = (Label)sender;

            if (LabelTapped.ClassId == "1")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if (LabelTapped.ClassId == "2")
            {
                return false;
            }

            return false;


        }
```

This is how I would call the PopupPage in a ContentPage:

```
var answer =  PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(new YesOrNotPopup());
```

From stack help :

```
// display the popup pahe 
     await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(new YesOrNotPopup ()
                            {
// instace the variable 
                                Message = "Submit your request?" ,
// instace the variable 
                                PrimaryButtonText = "Yes" ,
// instace the variable 
                                PrimaryCommand = new Command (async() =>
                                                               {
                                                                   Console.WriteLine("label1");

                                                               }) ,
// instace the variable 
                                SecondaryButtonText = "No" ,
// instace the variable 
                                SecondaryCommand = new Command ( async() =>
                                                               {
                                                                   Console.WriteLine("label2");
                                                               }) ,

                                            }
                            );
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of returning `bool` value, create two `Command`s in the `YesOrNotPopup`:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty PrimaryCommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(PrimaryCommand), typeof(ICommand), typeof(YesOrNotPopup));
public static readonly BindableProperty SecondaryCommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(SecondaryCommand), typeof(ICommand), typeof(YesOrNotPopup));

public ICommand PrimaryCommand
{
    get => ( ICommand ) this.GetValue ( PrimaryCommandProperty );
    set => this.SetValue ( PrimaryCommandProperty , value );
}
public ICommand SecondaryCommand
{
    get => ( ICommand ) this.GetValue ( SecondaryCommandProperty );
    set => this.SetValue ( SecondaryCommandProperty , value );
}
```

and bind them to the `Command`s properties of the `TapGestureRecognizer` of the two `Label`s.

Need more flexibilty over the control?

Create `PrimaryButtonText`, `SecondaryButtonText` and `Message` bindable properties..

XAML with binding:

```
<pages:PopupPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
                 WidthRequest="60"
                 HeightRequest="60"
                 Padding="30"
                 x:Class="MyApp.PopupPages.YesOrNotPopup "
                 x:Name="ThisPopUpPage" >
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="{Binding Message, Source={Reference ThisPopUpPage}}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>

        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Label x:Name="NoLabel" ClassId="1" Text="{Binding SecondaryButtonText, Source={Reference ThisPopUpPage}}">
                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding SecondaryCommand, Source={Reference ThisPopUpPage}}"/>
                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
            </Label>
            <Label x:Name="YesLabel" Text="{Binding PrimaryButtonText, Source={Reference ThisPopUpPage}}">
                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding PrimaryCommand, Source={Reference ThisPopUpPage}}"/>
                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
            </Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</pages:PopupPage>
```

Usage:

```
PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(new YesOrNotPopup {
{
    Message = "Submit your request?" ,
    PrimaryButtonText = "Yes" ,
    PrimaryCommand = new Command (async() =>
                                   {
                                       ShowLoading();
                                       await BookingService.BookRoom(booking);
                                       HideLoading();
                                   }) ,
    SecondaryButtonText = "No" ,
    SecondaryCommand = new Command (()=> /*do nothing*/)
});
```

Comment: Thanks , I am a beginner , where to use PrimaryCommandProperty/SecondaryCommandProperty and how to connect PrimaryButtonText to my Popup Xaml and all of this to my Popup Xaml

Comment: I have this error for both command "The name 'PrimaryCommandProperty' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: create accompanying static field with every bindable property, please read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties

Comment: @hugokis have youu seen the edit? I've added the static `BindableProperty` fields

Comment: i have this error : Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: 'Position 28:16. Can not find the object referenced by YesOrNotPopup'

Comment: I have added this in xaml :        <StackLayout.BindingContext>
            <local:YesOrNotPopup />
        </StackLayout.BindingContext> but the code crash

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I have update the code as you did but I hava this error :Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: 'Position 33:16. Can not find the object referenced by YesOrNotPopup'

Comment: I have update my question adding your help in the block 4

Comment: It looks like the reference in the xaml does not find my Popup Page "YesOrNotPopup"

Comment: You don't need to reference `local:YesOrNotPopup ` from other XAML pages, once you finish creating the page you can call it using `PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync` , but `<StackLayout.BindingContext> <local:YesOrNotPopup /> </StackLayout.BindingContext>` is not necessary

Comment: I have deleted it, the Popup apears but I do not have the value of Message,PrimaryButtonText,SecondaryButtonText

Comment: Have you read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties ?

Comment: Add these properties, I didn't include them in my answer as the are the same as other properties, just change the return type to be `string`